# Problema ao retornar varias routes no laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Eu tenho uma route que ao aceder `www.exemplo.com/comer` retorna uma view com o conteúdo.
O que estou a tentar fazer agora e criei outra route para fazer o mesmo efeito mas quando tento aceder www.exemplo.com/cesar-sousa não me retorna a view certa retorna a view do primeiro exemplo que dei acima.

Basicamente quero saber como posso criar routes para aceder a varias views diferentes mas com a posição da domínio sempre igual.

**Exemplo**

```
www.exemplo.com/comer ->EstabelecimentosController@estabelecimentos
www.exemplo.com/cesar-sousa -> PerfilUserController@perfil_user
```

Eu quero uma coisa assim mesma posição sempre a seguir a barra mas consoante mude o slug que esta armazenada na base de dados retorne o controller certo e a view certa.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('{slug_user_perfil}', 'PerfilUserController@perfil_user');
Route::get('{slug_categoria}', 'EstabelecimentosController@estabelecimentos');
```

---

E mais ou menos isso eu tenho os slugs armazenados na base de dados eu pretendo que dependendo do slug apresentado na URL ele saiba qual o controller que tem de usar e por si vai retornar a view correcta por eu coloquei duas routes com parâmetro slug mas quando tento aceder ao slug dos utilizadores ele retorna sempre o controller das categorias que por si retorna a view das categorias e esse o meu problema

Comment: Eu penso assim, isso é um erro... Se voce colocar o nome em vez da variável soluciona o problema....

Comment: Mas eu não posso por o nome pois o slug está armazenado na base de dados por isso é que estou a usar variável o que pretendo é qual a maneira de fazer com que cada slug que retorna na URL ele saiba qual a o controller que ele tem de usar

Comment: é o seguinte você colocou `Route::get('{slug_user_perfil}', 'PerfilUserController@perfil_user');` duas rotas iguais só que apontam para lugar diferentes, e isso não pode! se pode fazer diferente tipo: `Route::get('comer', 'PerfilUserController@perfil_user');` e `Route::get('cesar-souza', 'EstabelecimentosController@estabelecimentos');` com não são variaveis vai funcionar como rotas válidas ... o que você está tentando fazer vai dar choque de rotas e isso não pode e variável na rota raiz não é uma boa prática, pois limita sempre ser assim e pode confundir o sistemas de rotas como já acontece.

Comment: Mas tem que se por variável pois esses nomes são slugs armazenados na base de dados tem de haver uma forma de contornar isso pois imagina que tenho 100 utilizadores eu não vou fazer 100 rotas para casa utilizador acho que não faz sentido

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem a pergunta, basta criar uma função para testar o que foi passado como parâmetro:

```
Route::get('/{param?}', function ($param="default") {
    if( $param == "default")
        return view('welcome')
    else if( $param == "comer")
        return view('comer')
    return view('cesar-sousa');
});
```

Comment: É uma forma de prever o valor da rota, mas, isso pode trazer mais problemas limitando o sistemas de rotas sempre assim e ai você perde o MVC de separação de responsabilidade tendo apensas um `controller` para tudo ... Pra poucas rotas ou `single page` talvez até seja útil, mas, mesmo assim acho inválido se o sistema aumentar ...